# SonarQube: how to specify the sonar.source using * in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

My PL/SQL is stored in TFS in paths like these. In Jenkins TFS plugin: Project Path= `$/Server Artifacts/Schedule Snapshot 2013/SQL/EDBDEV.` Now how shall I specify the `sonar.source`?

```
$/Server Artifacts/Schedule Snapshot 2013/SQL/EDBDEV/ACCT/PROCEDURE
$/Server Artifacts/Schedule Snapshot 2013/SQL/EDBDEV/DMBO/PROCEDURE
```

I tried many like these, all give me an error:

```
[SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS] $ D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat -e -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.21.85.5:5432/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.dev.otpp.com/ ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS "-Dsonar.projectName=PL/SQL :: Schedule Snapshot 2013 :: EDBDEV" -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.projectKey=PLSQL.EDBDEV -Dsonar.sources=**\PROCEDURE
D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4

Unable to resolve path "**\PROCEDURE"

sonar.sources=**/PROCEDURE/*
sonar.sources=/**/PROCEDURE
sonar.sources=/.*/PROCEDURE/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [sonar.sources property](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) to limit the scope of the analysis to certain directories.

Comment: Appreciate if you can give me the exact rule in my case, that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: I ended up listing all the directories. Another question is: does sonar.sources recursively include the subfolders?